# Kafka Streams (Scala): Invalid topology: StateStore is not added yet

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology where I have a stream `A`.

From that stream `A`, I create a WindowedStore `S`.

```
       A  --> [S]
```

Then I want to make the objects in A transformed depending on data on `S`, and also these transformed objects to arrive to the WindowStore logic(via `transformValues`).

For that, I create a Transformer for that, creating a Stream `A'`, and making the windowing aware of it (i.e. now, `S` will be made from `A'`, not from `A`).

```
  A -> A'  --> [S]
       ^__read__|
```

But I cannot do that, because when I create the Topology, an exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore storeName is not added yet.
```

Is there a way to work this around? Is this a limitation?

Code example:

```scala
  // A 
  val sessionElementsStream: KStream[K, SessionElement] = ...
  // A'
  val sessionElementsTransformed : KStream[K, SessionElementTransformed] = {
    // Here we use the sessionStoreName - but it is not added yet to the Topology
    sessionElementsStream.
      transformValues(sessionElementTransformerSupplier, sessionStoreName)
  }

  val sessionElementsWindowedStream: SessionWindowedKStream[K, SessionElementTransformed] = {
    sessionElementsTransformed.
      groupByKey(sessionElementTransformedGroupedBy).
      windowedBy(sessionWindows)
  }

  val sessionStore : KTable[Windowed[K], List[WindowedSession]] = 
    sessionElementsWindowedStream.aggregate(
        initializer = List.empty[WindowedSession])(
        aggregator = anAggregator, merger = aMerger)(materialized = getMaterializedMUPKSessionStore(sessionStoreName))
```

The original problem, is that depending on previous sessions' values, I would like to change sessions after it. But if I do this in a transformer *after* the sessioning, these transformed sessions can be changed and sent  downstream - but they won't reflect their new state in `S` - so further requests to the store will have the old values.

Kafka Streams 2.1, Scala 2.12.4. 
Co-partitioned topics.

**UPDATE**

There is a way to do this within the DSL, using an extra topic:

- Sent A' `to` this topic
- Create `builder.stream` from this topic and build store from it.
- Define Store before you define the transformation (so the transformation step can use the Store, because it is already defined before).

However, it sounds cumbersome to have to use an extra topic here. Is there no other, simpler way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

> But I cannot do that, because when I create the Topology, an exception is thrown:
>
> ```
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore storeName is not added yet.
> ```

It looks like you simply forgot to literally "add" the state store to your processing topology, and then attach ("make available") the state store to your `Transformer`.

Here's a code snippet that demonstrates this (sorry, in Java).

Adding the state store to your topology:

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Long> myStateStore =
    Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
             Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("my-state-store-name"),
             Serdes.String(),
             Serdes.Long())
          .withCachingEnabled();
builder.addStateStore(myStateStore);
```

Attaching the state store to your `Transformer`:

```
final KStream<String, Double> stream = builder.stream("your-input-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));

final KStream<String, Long> transformedStream =
    stream.transform(new YourTransformer(myStateStore.name()), myStateStore.name());
```

And of course your `Transformer` must integrate the state store, with code like the following (this `Transformer` reads `<String, Double>` and writes `String, Long>`).

```
class MyTransformer implements TransformerSupplier<String, Double, KeyValue<String, Long>> {

  private final String myStateStoreName;

  MyTransformer(final String myStateStoreName) {
    this.myStateStoreName = myStateStoreName;
  }

  @Override
  public Transformer<String, Double, KeyValue<String, Long>> get() {
    return new Transformer<String, Double, KeyValue<String, Long>>() {

      private KeyValueStore<String, Long> myStateStore;
      private ProcessorContext context;

      @Override
      public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
        myStateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Long>) context.getStateStore(myStateStoreName);
      }

   // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do that for other PAPI-created table via the `StoreBuilder`.
But in this case, I'm creating the store via aggegation in the DSL - can I define it via the supplier too in order to add this store? Or, is there a way to get the supplier of the store created via DSL aggregation?

Comment: You can also name or supply state stores when working with the DSL.  Please check the API docs, I don't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: You can name DSL-created stores via `Materialized` if that's what you're referring to, but you can do that AFTER it has been created. And in order to create the store I need the input stream, which in turns uses this store - which is not defined yet, so it gives this error. Catch-22.

Comment: No, you can use `Materialized` to not just name state stores, but also to create stores (by passing a supplier, such as a `KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier`).  See https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html.

Comment: In this case, how do I get the supplier of a KTable-based store that has not yet been created?

Comment: You don't "get" one in this case, you create one yourself, and then pass it into the function. Here is one example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/StateStoresInTheDSLIntegrationTest.java. There are more in this repo.

Comment: The Supplier in the example is a TransformerSupplier(which I'm indeed using in a similar fashion, see `sessionElementsStream.transformValues(sessionElementTransformerSupplier, sessionStoreName))` in code above), not a StoreSupplier. Plus, it is using a PAPI-created store, not a DSL-created store. As you can see, in the example the store is created first because it is created via PAPI and has no upstream dependencies.